# How to provide implicit and explicit conversion ctr for same type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-conversion

Given a simple `template <typename T> struct X { T x, y; };`, I want to provide conversion constructors such that user can write:

```
X<double> a;
X<int16_t> b = a; // uses implicit conversion ctr (compiles with warning)
X<int16_t> c(a);  // uses explicit conversion ctr (compiles w/o warning)
X<int32_t> d = c; // uses implicit conversion ctr (compiles w/o warning)
```

I believe that to achieve this goal, I need to implement both, an implicit and an explicit conversion constructor from type `U`. But it's not possible to overload on "implicit" and `explicit`:

```
template <typename T> struct X {
     X(T x = T(), T y = T()) : x(x), y(y) {}

     // implicit conversion
     template <typename U> 
     X(const X<U>& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}

     // not possible!
     template <typename U> 
     explicit X(const X<U>& other)
         : x(static_cast<T>(other.x))
         , y(static_cast<T>(other.y)) 
     {}

     T x, y;
};
```

How could I achieve this goal (I guess I can't...)?

My initial thought was that <strike>I need to enable/disable the one or other depending on `is_lossless_convertible`. So is there a suitable type trait?</strike>

I would like to test if a *scalar* type `U` is convertible to type `T` without loss of precision:

```
using namespace std;
static_assert(is_lossless_convertible<int16_t, int32_t>::value == true);
static_assert(is_lossless_convertible<int32_t, int16_t>::value == false);
static_assert(is_lossless_convertible<int16_t, uint32_t>::value == false);
static_assert(is_lossless_convertible<int32_t, double>::value == true);
static_assert(is_lossless_convertible<double, int32_t>::value == false);
```

In short, it should yield `true` if `std::is_convertible<U, T>::value == true` **and** if `U x; T y = x;` would not issue a compiler warning regarding loss of information.

Comment: No, there isn't one. You have to build your own. Note that you cannot control warnings emitted without resorting to compiler extensions (is there a compiler with such an extension? I don't know of any).

Comment: In fact, I realize that I'm looking at the problem the wrong way. I'll update my question.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You're right - the only problematic requirement is the warning, which I cannot control. If I drop this, then I only need to implement the explicit conversion ctr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't overload on explicitness, but you *can* provide an explicit converting constructor and implicit conversion operator:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> struct S {
   S() {}
   template<typename U> explicit S(const S<U> &) { std::cout << "explicit\n"; }
   template<typename U> operator S<U>() { return S<U>(this); }
private:
   template<typename U> friend struct S;
   template<typename U> S(const S<U> *) { std::cout << "implicit\n"; }
};

int main() {
   S<double> sd;
   S<int> si1(sd);
   S<int> si2 = sd;
}
```

Output:

```
explicit
implicit
```

Tested with gcc and clang.

The explicit converting constructor is preferred to the implicit conversion operator because in the latter case there is an additional (possibly elided) call to the copy constructor of `S<int>`.

Comment: That's very very nice! Thanks!